# PhpStorm insert current namespace

Tags: phpstorm

I want the PhpStorm to insert current namespace by default or with a hotkey or with live templates.

Whet I create new Php class ("New | PHP Class" dialog) there is a field for a namespace. Is there a way for it to be filled automatically? It does not look a big deal because in my case a namespace is just directory path (I use composer) starting from `src`. My search efforts did not give my anything about this at all. Looks like PhpStrom does not have this feauture. But maybe there is some plugin or a hack?

Comment: *"Whet I create new Php class there is a field for a namespace. Is there a way for it to be filled automatically?"* Where? In "New | PHP Class" dialog? it is filled automatically. If it does not -- you did not configure your project correctly (e.g. no Source Root defined).

Comment: @LazyOne you are right. Did not configure source root

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`New | PHP Class` dialog should fill the namespace automatically based on the directory where file will be created. If it does not then you have not configured your project properly.

`Settings/Preferences | Directories` -- ensure that your `src` folder is marked as **Source Root**. That's depends on project, of course: for Laravel project you need to map `app` folder to `App\` namespace (typical case).

PhpStorm can also detect source roots from your `composer.json` settings and can even keep it in sync since 2017.2 version (see https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/07/configuring-with-composer-in-phpstorm-2017-2/).

Some links to read (official help pages):

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-php-namespaces-in-a-project.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-content-roots.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories.html

Comment: Is there a way to insert namespace in other ways? I mean not in `New | PHP Class`. Is there some snippet or a hotkey?

Comment: Please share it. I need it in case I moved a file to a different directory for example.

Comment: @FreeLightman *"Please share it"* Oh, sorry -- I've missed "not" word there. *"I need it in case I moved a file to a different directory for example"* use appropriate refactoring (e.g. invoke "Refactor | Move" on class name) instead of just moving files -- it takes care of that.